# Why does this compile in Java7 and does not in Java8?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-7, java-8

Generics are tricky.
And looks like they are treated differently in different versions of Java.

This code successfully compiles in Java 7 and fails to compile with Java 8.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enum foo = null;
    tryCompile(EnumSet.of(foo));
  }

  static <C extends Enum<C> & Another> void tryCompile(Iterable<C> i) {}

  static interface Another {}
}
```

Here is an error message from Java 8. I used this one to compile it: http://www.compilejava.net/

```
/tmp/java_A7GNRg/Main.java:6: error: method tryCompile in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
    tryCompile(EnumSet.of(foo));
    ^
  required: Iterable<C>
  found: EnumSet
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Enum
    upper bound(s): Enum<Enum>,Another
  where C is a type-variable:
    C extends Enum<C>,Another declared in method <C>tryCompile(Iterable<C>)
/tmp/java_A7GNRg/Main.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method of in class EnumSet is applied to given types
    tryCompile(EnumSet.of(foo));
                         ^
  required: E
  found: Enum
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Enum<E> declared in method <E>of(E)
1 error
1 warning
```

The question is about the difference between versions of Java compiler.

Comment: What does Java 8 complain about?

Comment: Indeed, the compilation error in Java 8 *ought to* explain why it is not compiling.  And it quite possibly does ....

Comment: What do you expect this code code to do? Also, your `Enum` is a raw-type.

Comment: Without an error message, it's hard to guess what's going on here, but I would guess that the compiler is able to (correctly) infer that `EnumSet.of(foo)` has type `EnumSet<Enum>` which is not compatible with the bound `C extends Enum<C> & Another`.

Comment: Done, error output added to the question. How does it help though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main difference between Java 7 and Java 8 is the target type inference. While Java 7 only considers the parameters of a method invocation to determine the type arguments, Java 8 will use the target type of an expression, i.e. the parameter type in case of a nested method invocation, the type of the variable that is initialized or assigned to, or the method’s return type in case of a `return` statement.

E.g. when writing, `List<Number> list=Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);`, Java 7 will infer the type `List<Integer>` for the right hand side by looking at the method’s arguments and generate an error while Java 8 will use the target type `List<Number>` to infer the constraint that the method arguments must be instances of `Number` which is the case. Therefore, it is legal in Java 8.

If you are interested in the formal details, you may study the [“Java Language Specification, Chapter 18. Type Inference”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), especially [§18.5.2. Invocation Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2), however, that’s not easy reading…

So what happens when you say `Enum foo = null; tryCompile(EnumSet.of(foo));`?

In Java 7 the type of the expression `EnumSet.of(foo)` will be inferred by looking at the type of the argument, `foo` which is the raw type `Enum`, hence an unchecked operation will be performed and the result type is the raw type `EnumSet`. This type implements the raw type `Iterable` and hence can be passed to `tryCompile` forming another unchecked operation.

In Java 8 the target type of `EnumSet.of(foo)` is the type of the first parameter of `tryCompile` which is `Iterable<C extends Enum<C> & Another>`, so without going too much into details, in Java 7 `EnumSet.of` will be treated as raw type invocation because it has a raw type argument, in Java 8 it will be treated as generic invocation because it has a generic target type. By treating it as as a generic invocation, the compiler will conclude that the type found (`Enum`) is not compatible to the required type `C extends Enum<C> & Another`. While you could get away with assigning the raw type `Enum` to `C extends Enum<C>` with an unchecked warning, it will considered to be incompatible with `Another` (without a type-cast).

You can indeed insert such a cast:

```
Enum foo = null;
tryCompile(EnumSet.of((Enum&Another)foo));
```

This compiles, of course not without an unchecked warning due to the assignment of `Enum` to `C extends Enum<C>`.

You can also dissolve the target type relationship so that the same steps as in Java 7 are performed:

```
Enum foo = null;
EnumSet set = EnumSet.of(foo);
tryCompile(set);
```

Here, raw types are used throughout the three lines so this compiles with unchecked warnings and the same ignorance about the `implements Another` constraint as in Java 7.

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. Any chance you know a source I can read to be able to get things like that out of the top of my head? And yes, not a JLS, something more... readable.

Comment: There is a brief introduction to target typing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing). For a general “what’s new in Java 8” you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html). You might find a lot of other sites in the internet telling similar using other words and more examples, however, I don’t know of a site going substantially deeper without being too formal.

Answer (score 2):

The type inference engine in Java 8 has been improved, and (I assume) is now able to determine that the `C` type does not extend `Another`.

In Java 7 the type inference system wasn't able to, or didn't bother determining that the `Another` type was missing, and gave the programmer the benefit of the doubt (at compile time).

You will still pay for the transgression at runtime if you call methods on the `Another` interface at runtime in Java 7.

For example, this code:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Main {

  static enum Foo {
    BAR
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enum foo = Foo.BAR;
    tryCompile(EnumSet.of(foo));
  }

  static <C extends Enum<C> & Another> void tryCompile(Iterable<C> i) {
    i.iterator().next().doSomething();
  }

  static interface Another {
    void doSomething();
  }
}
```

Will produce this error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Main$Foo cannot be cast to Main$Another
    at Main.tryCompile(Main.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Even though the Java 7 compiler will compile the code, it still gives warnings about raw types and unchecked invocations which should alert you to something being amiss.

---

Here is a pretty straightforward example not using an enum, but modeled on the definition of `Enum` that exhibits the same problem.  Compiles with warnings in Java 7, but not in Java 8:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  static class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
  }

  static class FooA extends Foo<FooA> {
  }

  public static <T extends Foo<T>> List<T> fooList(T e) {
    return Collections.singletonList(e);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new FooA();
    tryCompile(fooList(foo));
  }

  static <C extends Enum<C> & Another> void tryCompile(Iterable<C> i) {
    i.iterator().next().doSomething();
  }

  static interface Another {
    void doSomething();
  }
}
```

So it isn't an `Enum` specific issue, but it may be because of the recursive types involved.

Comment: Nah, runtime exceptions are expected. I agree. But if you try to replace Enum with your Foo one, compilation would break saying something about another. So this is Enum-specific issue, from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, but then the compiler can work out that `Foo` does not implement the `Another` interface.  I don't think it's enum specific, but probably is specific to classes with type parameters.  Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a correct error to me:

> ```
> reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
>   inferred: Enum
>   upper bound(s): Enum<Enum>,Another
> ```

`EnumSet.of(foo)` will have type `EnumSet<Enum>`, which is not compatible with `C extends Enum<C> & Another`, for the same reason that `Set<Enum>` is not compatible with `Set<? extends Enum>`, since Java generics are invariant.

Comment: Then it would not compile in Java 7. It does.

Comment: Enum in Java has a type `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`, so it matches `C extends Enum<C>` as far as I can tell.

Comment: My current best guess here is that it's a rawtypes issue. If you explicitly type foo as `Enum<Enum>` does it work then?

Comment: Try it out using http://www.compilejava.net It's fascinating! Enum<Enum> is not a valid type, Enum<?> also fails to compile.

Answer (score -1):

this compiles fine for me in Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600 with the   Eclipse JDT (Java Development Tools) Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2)  1.0.0.v20140317-1956    org.eclipse.jdt.java8patch.feature.group    Eclipse.org installed.

i get a few warnings (raw type on foo and Unchecked invocation on tryCompile.

Comment: If you are getting warnings its going to compile as java 7.. You need to compile as java 8 complete

Comment: oops, looks like i lied. you are correct, i was compiling to 1.7 :(