# Java 8 Incompatible Types

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, compatibility, javac

Here's the simple code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> maps = newArrayList(
        createMap("1", "a", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.EMPTY_MAP),
        createMap("2", "b", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.EMPTY_MAP),
        createMap("3", "c", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.EMPTY_MAP)
    ); 

    System.out.println(" maps = " + maps);
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> createMap(String value1, String value2, Map<String, Object> object1, Map<String, Object> object2) {
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put("value1", value1);
       map.put("value1", value1);
       map.put("object1", object1);
       map.put("object2", object2);
       return map;
    }    

    public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(E... elements) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(elements.length);
    Collections.addAll(list, elements);
    return list;
    }
}
```

When JAVA_HOME points to JDK 8 and I use `javac -source 1.7 SimpleTest.java` I get

```
SimpleTest.java:9: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Map> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>
        final ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> maps = newArrayList(
                                                                ^
```

When I use `-source 1.8` or no `-source` option everything works ok. Now, when JAVA_HOME points to JDK 7 the code always compiles whether I use `-source 1.7` or not.

Initially this question was about a piece of software where POM file has a `<source>` and `<target>` set to `1.7` and the build was failing on JDK 8 but was ok on JDK 7.

Now for the question - what causes it to happen ? It seems to me as a major overlook of some sort. Why compiling on JDK 8 with `source` set to `1.7` fails ?

Comment: So, are you saying that this code compiles with JDK 7 but does not with JDK 8?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. More so, compiler settings in Maven set to source being 1.7 in both cases

Comment: Please define explicitely what we are comparing here. Are you compiling with a JDK 8 compiler or 7? Or are you compiling with a JDK 8 compiler with source 1.8 for Maven and JDK 7 compiler with source 1.7? Also, the code you posted doesn't have a `java.util.ArrayList< java.util.Map>` (with raw types) so I'm not sure how you got that error.

Comment: Works for me on JDK 8 with source set to 1.8, but gives exactly the same error when source set to 1.7 (same JDK). NetBeans 8.0.2 here.

Comment: In both cases source is set to 1.7. However same code compiles when JAVA_HOME points to JDK 8 and does not compile when JAVA_HOME points to JDK 7. As for the `ArrayList` not being in the code, that what `Lists.newArrayList` creates. This is a class from Google Guava.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, that is what I am looking for an answer for.  Why source 1.7 doesn't work for JDK 8.

Comment: Which version of Guava are you using?

Comment: @Tunaki: Guava is irrelevant here. This example can be simplified to reproduce the problem without any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the code to a self-contained example which doesn’t need 3rd-party libraries:

```
public class Test2 {
    @SafeVarargs
    static <T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList(T... arg) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(arg));
    }
    private final List<Map<String, Object>> maps = newArrayList(
        createMap(null, Collections.EMPTY_MAP)
     );

    public static Map<String, Object> createMap(String id, Map<String,String> m) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can be compiled using `javac` from jdk1.7, but not with `javac` from jdk1.8 using `-source 1.7`.

The point here is that `javac` from jdk1.8 still is a different compiler than the one included in the previous version and the option `-source 1.7` doesn’t tell it to mimic the old implementation’s behavior but to be compatible with the Java 7 *specification*. If the old compiler has a bug, the newer compiler doesn’t have to try to reproduce the bug.

Since the code uses `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` rather than `Collections.<String,String>emptyMap()`, the raw type `Map` will be passed to `createMap`, making it an unchecked invocation having the raw result type `Map`.

This is mandated by [JLS §15.12.2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6):

> The result type of the chosen method is determined as follows:
>
> - If the chosen method is declared with a return type of void, then the result is void.
> - Otherwise, if unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable, then the result type is the erasure (§4.6) of the method's declared return type.
>
> …

It seems that this behavior has not been (fully) implemented in `javac` of jdk1.7. Interestingly, it will do it correctly when adding a type parameter like

```
public static <T> Map<String, Object> createMap(String id, Map<String,String> m)
```

making it a generic method. Then, jdk1.7 will produce the same error. But the cited rule applies to *all* method invocations.

---

In contrast, the fact that compiling it with Java 8 compliance succeeds stems from the new target type inference, which has entirely different rules.

Comment: I guess, I edited the question as you were posting your answer with suggestion. One question that's left is why `-source 1.8` makes JDK 8 compiler compile it ?

Comment: That's right, I saw the edit after submitting the answer. But the last sentence summarizes it, the Java 8 rules are totally different. The generic signature of the `newArrayList` invocation is derived from the target type. Note that when you change the invocation to `Test2.<Map<String, Object>>newArrayList(...)` it will also work in Java 7 conformingly, though there are still some subtle differences to how it works in Java 8. Explaining the Java 8 rules completely would exceed the scope of the answer. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285613/2711488) explains some differences.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to that answer.