# wildcard in generics behave different in Java 7 and 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7

I have this code which compiles fine when compiled as Java 7 (Eclipse compiler) but fails when I set the project settings to Java 8:

```
package scratch;

class Param<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  public Comparable<?> get() {
    return null;
  }
}

public class Condition<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Condition<T> isInRange(T lower, T upper) {
    return null;
  }

  public void foo() {
    Comparable bound = null;                 // Line 15 
    Param<?> param = new Param<Double>();
    Condition.isInRange(param.get(), bound); // Line 17
  }
}
```

In Java 7, I get these warnings:

- line 15: Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable should be parameterized
- line 17: Type safety: Unchecked invocation isInRange(Comparable, Comparable) of the generic method isInRange(T, T) of type Condition

When I add `<?>` in line 15, the warning is gone, but I then get an error in line 17:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method isInRange(T, T) of type
>   Condition is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Comparable, Comparable). The inferred
>   type Comparable is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter >

Does anyone know what exactly causes this incompability?

PS: I added these ugly casts to make the code compile under both versions of Java:

```
    Condition.isInRange((Comparable)param.get(), (Comparable) bound);
```

Comment: The eclipse compiler has some bugs with regards to generics, so you should test with `javac`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the wildcard, but with the *raw type* of the `bound` variable. In Java-7, this effectively turns off all checks regarding the `isInRange` method invocation. In Java-8, the target typing still detects the invalidity of the nested invocation, similar to [this scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285613/2711488). I don’t understand, why you think your type casts to the raw `Comparator` are uglier than the initial usage of the raw type. Of course, the second type cast is nonsensical as `bound` is already a raw `Comparable`.

Comment: @Kayaman: in this case, Eclipse is perfectly in line with `javac`.

Comment: @Kayaman: I tested with javac and got the same reasults.

Comment: @Holger: Yes, both versions are ugly. Still have no idea how to make it look less ugly though.

Comment: Why are you using raw types? Don't use raw types, unless you absolutely have to because you're dealing with old (pre-generics) code that you can't change.

Comment: Well, there is no solution derivable from this example code. The method `isInRange` can’t accept a `Comparable<?>`, as that type is incompatible with the required parameter type. You can inhibit the generic type checking by incorporating raw types, but the correct solution would be to prevent getting a `Comparable<?>` in the first place. But we can’t derive from your example, why you have these incomplete types…

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not an expert on generics so my answer could be incorrect. I believe the issue is the way the `isInRange` method is defined.

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

This is a recursive definition, which is not a problem in itself. Look at classes like `Double`, `Long`. I believe that because of how recursive definition is resolved, the types to the method (`isInRange`) must be a class that implements `Comparable` that uses itself as the generic for `Comparable`; e.g., `class C implements Comparable<C>`